# Setting the font size of geom_text to match ggplot theme font size

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I need the font size to match the theme font size in a ggplot.

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(123)
n_points <- 10
data <- data.frame(
  x = runif(n_points, min = 0, max = 10),
  y = runif(n_points, min = 0, max = 10),
  label = letters[1:n_points]
)

# Create a scatter plot with points and text labels
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(y))) +  # Add points
  geom_text(aes(label = label, color=factor(y)), size = 10, vjust = -0.5) +  # Add text labels
  theme_minimal() +  # Use a minimal theme
    theme(text = element_text(size=10))
```

As you can see, `geom_text(aes(size = 10))` but is not actually font size 10 as `theme(text = element_text(size=10))`

How can I match the geom text font size to that of the theme?

Comment: Use `size = 10/.pt` inside `geom_text`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Remove  'size = 10'  from geom_text and see if it solves your problem: geom_text(aes(label = label, color=factor(y)), vjust = -0.5)

Comment: @Rodrigo, no that doesn't matter, it defaults to a size. The 'size = 10/.pt' argument tis needed.